# how to set different themes for diferent users in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

**how to set different themes for diferent Logged In  users in magento?**

consider customer with email id 1@gmail.com is logged in, he will see theme with red color,
while the customer logged in with 2@gmail.com will see theme with blue color 
or even i want to set the complete different shop look for different customers

Please post only working stuff which may be tested as i need it in hurry.

thanks

Comment: Mage SE is a place to post questions, not requests for fully working extensions. Your question is a valid one but you can not expect people here to build you a fully working feature in a hurry

Comment: no you are getting it wrong i dont expect any extension lol
refer below the magik tejas i wanted some answers like him bt thats wrong code i am just looking for a logic of code to add so different session can have different theme 
hope you got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code -

```
<?php
     if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
     Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')->setPackageName('package_name')->setTheme('themename');
     }
?>
```

Comment: Mage::getDesign()->setPackageName('package_name')->setTheme('themename'); ??
this is just setting the theme for logged in users 
pls read my question brother

Comment: Nice one @MagikTejas, tho this is just part of what op needs. If you want, expand your answer with the observer that executes this piece of code and the attribute per customer where the specific theme is stored

Answer (score 0):

I think `**you have to check manually for each customer to change theme and package**` or you have take one array and take 
some static value in check this email in array if exist then apply your theme otherwise not.

```
$customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer_email = $customerData->getData('email');
if($customer_email=="1@gmail.com")
{
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')->setPackageName('package_name')->setTheme('themename');
}
elseif($customer_email=="2@gmail.com")
{
    Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')->setPackageName('package_name')->setTheme('themename');
}
```